# tikz shape fill not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I am trying to define a shape as the attached yellow filled one. However, when I place the lines inside, the fill does not work properly and the rectangle's green background shows through. I have two questions:

1) How can I fix this in the code below?
2) Is there a way to define this as a shape that I can use as a regular shape? I am afraid I don't know tikz or pgf sufficiently to be able to do that.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

\node\[rectangle,draw,fill=green,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm\] (test) at (0,0) {};
 \draw\[fill=yellow\] (0,0) -- (0,0.6) -- (0.4,0.6) -- (0.4,0) -- (0.2,-0.1) -- (0,0) -- cycle 
(0,0.2) -- (0.2,0.15) -- (0.4,0.2) 
(0,0.4) -- (0.2,0.35) -- (0.4,0.4)
node (ar1) {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly correct your editor so that next time you don't post code with spurious characters like the one in `\[` and `![\documentclass{minimal}` and don't use `minimal` class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't advice beginners to venture in to the jungle of defining new shapes using `pgf` (low level of tikz). You can draw the shape instead and re-use it using `pic` facility provided by `tikz` version 3. Though I don't claim to have understood your needs properly, here is an attempt using `pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\tikzset{
         myshape/.pic={
        code={
            \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (0,0.6) -- (0.4,0.6) -- (0.4,0) -- (0.2,-0.1) -- (0,0)
             -- cycle;
             \draw (0,0.2) -- (0.2,0.15) -- node[pos=0.1,above=-0.7ex,font=\tiny] (ar1) {fg}(0.4,0.2);
             \draw (0,0.4) -- (0.2,0.35) -- (0.4,0.4);             
  }}
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}    
   \node[rectangle,draw,fill=green,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] (test) at (0,0) {};
   \path (0,0) pic {myshape};    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much. This may do for now. I was hoping that I could define it as a shape so that I can declare a node to be of that shape and position it relative to another shape (e.g., above the rectangle node) rather than absolute positioning. I suppose that requires more machinery!...

Comment: @ozsu That require some `pgf` code. This site has some examples though if you search for example: [Making a PGF shape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33532).

Comment: Thanks much. This will do for now. I will spend time learning pdf a bit more when I get a chance.